# Showing that $A/J \cong \mathbb C.$

Tags: ideals, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, quotient-spaces, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Consider the $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A = C_0(\mathbb R)$ and the ideal $J = \{f \in A\ |\ f(0) = 0 \}$ of $A.$ Show that $A/J \cong \mathbb C$ as $C^{\ast}$-algebras.

Here $J$ is clearly a closed maximal ideal of $A$ since it is the kernel of a non-zero multiplicative linear functional on $A$ namely the evaluation $f \mapsto f(0).$ So it is obvious that $A/J$ happens to be a field. But how do I make sure that it is the field of complex numbers $\mathbb C$ as a $C^{\ast}$-algebra? Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't get it. I just looked up the definition of a C*-algebra (possibly for the first time in my life, so I may be missing something). Why wouldn't complex conjugation work as the adjoint? Also, if you have seen the example that $M_n(\Bbb{C})$ is a C*-algebra then you are done.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen$:$ What do you mean by adjoint? Do you mean involution? BTW I have to show that $A/J$ is $\mathbb C$ as a $C^{\ast}$-algebra. What is the underlying isomorphism you are referring to here? I am not getting you, sorry.

Comment: “Let $A=C_0(\mathbb R)$ be a $C^*$-algebra.” That isn’t enough. What is $A?$ Not all $C^*$-algebras have functions as their elements. What does $C_0(\mathbb R)$ actually mean?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the slip.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews$:$ In this case I am not dealing with an arbitrary $C^{\ast}$-algebra; Rather I am fixing a $C^{\ast}$-algebra which consists of all complex valued continuous functions defined on the real line vanishing at $\infty$ which one might think of as the collection of all continuous functions defined on $\mathbb S^1$ (one point compactification of $\mathbb R$) vanishing at a point of it and I am trying to work on it.

Comment: Then put that in the question, @AntonioClaire.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews$:$ I have already mentioned it in my question. I don't think that I need to clarify it further.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews$:$ Edited it accordingly. Hope it clarifies the ambiguity you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the first isomorphism theorem for $C^*$-algebras:

**Theorem:** Let $\varphi: A \to B$ be a $*$-homomorphism between $C^*$-algebras. Then the induced map
$$\overline{\varphi}: A/\ker(\varphi) \to \varphi(B): a + \ker (\varphi)\mapsto \varphi(a)$$
is a well-defined $*$-isomorphism.

Apply this to the canonical $*$-homomorphism
$$\operatorname{ev}_0: C_0(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{C}: f \mapsto f(0).$$